# Error al ecribir en Python Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación, y actualmente estoy realizando un curso por Youtube de Python. Cuestión, tuve que descargarme *Sublime Text 3*; el profesor nos dijo los pasos a seguir como instalar el package control y demás, pero al momento de escribir por ejemplo `print ("Prueba")`, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> No se encontró Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuración > Administrar los alias de ejecución de aplicaciones. [Finished in 3.4s].

¿Qué debería hacer?

Aquí las instrucciones que el profesor nos dio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yppT6GPZMyo&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS&index=3 **(desde el minuto 10:50)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que no has instalado correctamente python según lo que cuentas. Para verificar si lo que digo es cierto, te recomiendo abrir una nueva terminal y simplemente escribe `python`. Si ves que sale un error diciendo que el programa no se encuentra, intenta descargarlo de nuevo desde [la pagina oficial](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Si por algún motivo sigue sin funcionar, verifica que el path al interprete este dentro del PATH. Si necesitas mas ayuda respóndeme y lo vemos, saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, al final era que python; como vos decías, no estaba bien instalado.